# Tomcat Exception-Type Ignoring Specific Exception for More General

Tags: tomcat, web, error-handling

For one type of exception, `IOException`, I want to display one page. For all other exceptions I have a default error page. In my web.xml I have things setup like this:

```
 <error-page>
  <exception-type>java.io.IOException</exception-type>
  <location>/queryException.jsp</location>
 </error-page>

 <error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
  <location>/error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
```

The problem is the `error.jsp` is the only page that ever shows, even if an `IOException` is thrown. The order the tags appear in doesn't matter; if I remove the `java.lang.Exception` tag though, I can get `queryException.jsp` to show for `IOExceptions`. What is the solution here? How can I keep a general error page for all exceptions EXCEPT for those with specific pages?

Comment: Am able to replicate the same problem and tried with <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type> but still it does not work. Another example here http://www.coderanch.com/t/443600/Servlets/java/Overriding-exception-type-tag-web

Answer (score 0):

"What is the solution here? How can I keep a general error page for all exceptions EXCEPT for those with specific pages?"

You are not able to do this...You will need to move in a direction other than a general error page for all your exceptions.